# How do i link two edit pages when i click edit button?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I have two view pages with output field. When I click edit button I want to edit both of them. Is there any way I can do it?

I found the code for one view page edit and save.

```
public Boolean bEditMode {

    get {
        if(bEditMode == null) {
            bEditmode = false;
        }
        return bEditMode;
    }
    set;
}

public PageReference doToggleEditMode() {
  bEditMode = !bEditMode;
  return null;
}

public PageReference doSave() {
    try {  // Do your stuff to save your record 
        doToggleEditMode();
    } catch(Exception ex) { 
        // Handle error 
    } 
    return null;
}
```

How do i add this code two page?

Comment: Hey can you please tell how put space and html tags in stack exchange ? Thanks

Comment: Hi danzi, if you edit the question, put the HTML in, highlight it, and then click on the code button in the toolbar (it's the pair of braces) it'll sort it out for you.

Alternatively you can put code between two back ticks (usually the key below Escape) or simply indent each line with four spaces.